# click button VBA to update a drop down field to a specific value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm wanting a button to perform multiple actions. when clicked it should:
add 1 to dial attempts field
change the "leagGenOutcome" to "no answer"

the problem is that the "leadGenOutcome" is a dropdown field taking it's options from another table.

I used this VBA code which works for a field with no drop down, but doesn't work on the drop down field.

```
Private Sub AddDialAttBTN_Click()

    DialAttempts = DialAttempts + 1
    
    LeadGenOutcome = "no answer"
    
End Sub
```

I know I must be missing something simple to get this to work. any help is much appreciated.
EDIT
by "doesn't work" the DialAttempts counter ticks up as it should but a "run time error" displays stating "the value you entered isnt valid for this field"
LimitToList property is Yes
"no answer" is a listed item
the field that LeadGenOutcome is bound to is called LeadGenOutcome01 in a form called LeadGenOutcomes.

currently it's a test database which I am using to learn how best to arrange and format.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Is combobox LimitToList property set to yes? Is "no answer" a listed item? What is the field that LeadGenOutcom is bound to?

Comment: Hi June7, thanks for your comment, I've updated the question with the information requested. thanks

Comment: Is the combobox bound to a field that is set up as a Lookup in table? Is it a number type? The error message is quite clear. Can't save a text string to a number field.

Comment: Hi June7, thank you for the direction on this. must feel like explaining an Iphone to a monkey. I've sorted the problem by changing "no answer" to "2" which is the id for that outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed "no answer" to "2" which is the ID for that response in the linked form. I had thought that it would display as "2" and not the associated text. this is not the case. thank you June7 for the assist.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).